# Gitlab wont start on reboot

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, gitlab, boot, init

I installed gitlab 8.4 from source using this guide - http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/install/installation.html on Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm having trouble getting it started on boot.

I used these commands from the tutorial to make the init script and run it on boot.

```
sudo cp lib/support/init.d/gitlab /etc/init.d/gitlab
sudo cp lib/support/init.d/gitlab.default.example /etc/default/gitlab
sudo update-rc.d gitlab defaults 21
```

sudo service gitlab start works just fine but when the server is rebooted, gitlab wont start and nginx shows 502 Bad Gateway in browser.

What could be the problem?

Comment: It seems that the init.d script has su - git added and that prompts for password and that is why it doesnt start.